# Adding Parallax to the Pacific squarespace template?

Tags: jquery, html, css, squarespace

Is there at all any way to add parallaxing to squarespace?

I understand if there isn't, as it's quite a tall order. But if not, what would be an alternative? Theories? Guesses? Anything?

I do know that squarespace allows the implementation of jquery, not sure if that helps but I just wanted to pick some of your guys brains and ask just to ask.

Thanks!

So far I have customized it very slightly... Editing the navbar mostly.

Site link: - http://xavier-jackson.squarespace.com

CSS custom code used so far:

Hide some nav items

```
.nav-wrapper > nav > div:nth-child(2),
.nav-wrapper > nav > div:nth-child(3),
.nav-wrapper > nav > div:nth-child(6)
{
  display:none !important;
}
```

Make nav semitransparent

```
#showOnScrollWrapper{
/* nice browsers */
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
```

As always all help is well appreciated.

Comment: If you have the possibility to manipulate the Dom and adding scripts then yes it is possible though with parallax it's best to have the option to manipulate the Dom without js but if not we can do it with js

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Not too sure what you are referring to when you say DOM. Do you mean Document Object Model? If so then squarespace has an option to edit the CSS or to add javascript. But I'm not sure what would be the code to add parallaxing elements to the page.

Comment: Do you have the option to edit the HTML somewhere if not we'll have to do it with js

Comment: I wish, this is one of the the main drawbacks of squarespace. They have no accessible HTML editor. Just JS and CSS. The only exception is if a "markdown block" is used as seen here: http://help.squarespace.com/guides/using-the-markdown-block  but it is limited in that it only allows "inner-content" editing. That is, it is only able to make changes to content within that block or div, but not affecting the main website code directly.

Comment: Well I'm not even positive if it needs to be changed. I don't see any example HTML in your question